# Titanium : ScrollView not scrolling with horizontal layout

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

Im trying to put Images into scrollView. 
The following test case does not work with horizontal layout on Android:

```
var scrollImages = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    height : 230,
    width : Titanium.UI.FILL,
    layout : 'horizontal'
});

arrayPic.forEach(function(item) {
    scrollImages.add(getImageInView(item));
});

function getImageInView(imaeUrl) {
    var view = Ti.UI.createView({
        height : 230,
        width : Alloy.Globals.deviceWidth * 0.75,
        left : 10
    });

    var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : imaeUrl,
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        width : Ti.UI.SIZE
    });
    $.addClass(imageView, 'defaultImage');
    view.add(imageView);
    return view;
}
```

Works fine on iOS.

Comment: what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @RenePot The scrollView cant scroll horizontally.

Comment: Can you try adding contentWidth : Ti.UI.SIZE or to the calculated width in pixels for scrollview and see if that works?

Comment: Yes I did @Soumya :(

Comment: I had to add scrollType : 'horizontal', works fine now,  thank you :D